# Unable to Load the form tag handler

Tags: hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
```

---

**Getting an error on first tag of the form as -**

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="budgetmaster" class="from-horizontal">
```

---

**Unable to load tag handler class "org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag" for tag "form:form"**

**The Problem is it is working correct for one form. but not working for another form.**

My not working form is exactly same as working form. the error is getting solved by writing prefix something else than the **form** but then the form which is opening is not allowed to write something in input box.

And in netbeans it's showing error as **with root cause `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'budgetmaster' available as request attribute`**

Comment: and attribute `class` is there in that other working form too?Show the code for other working form.

Comment: yes it's there. it's a css class.

Comment: Working form code   <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="user" class="form-horizontal">

Comment: my not working form is exactly same as working form. the error is getting solved by writing prefix something else then the **form** but then the form which is opening is not allowed to write something in input box

Comment: and in netbeans it's showing error as  "with root cause
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'budgetmaster' available as request attribute"

Comment: ported your comments to question.

Comment: ohhk thank you. but can you give to some solution for this problem

Comment: I am not very sure but seems your this form is not being rendered via controller but directly. Missing attribute problem occurs due to this or some name mismatches in field names. Hard to debug without full code base.

Comment: ohhk thank so much.

Comment: What you have posted is not an answer. You can put that in question & delete answer. I see that attribute name set in controller is - `budget` & not `budgetmaster` as declared in form tag so that is the reason for issue.

Comment: Thank you, So much :)  ya that was the only error. thanks a lot @SabirKhan